# Need help to scroll images

Tags: android, image, scroll

I need to display some images which can be scrolled horizontally. Only one image should be visible on the screen. It should be like iphone screen, which has multiple 4 or more screen and display the items per screen and shows how many screens left as small circles at the bottom. Like that I have show the small circles as many as the images. I tried GestureListener, but it scroll only a single image. Any suggestions pls..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at android.widget.AdapterView and android.widget.Gallery: These are standard Android widgets that provide scrolling through images. However, this will not look like the UI you describe (iOS look&feel) but like an Android app...

See this example code:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Gallery1.html